# Flask app cannot open server to Google Cloud Compute instance external IP

Tags: flask, cloud, google-compute-engine

I can't get my Flask API to respond to API calls using my instance external IP.

I've setup an instance using the Google Cloud Compute running `Ubuntu 18.04`, already opened up `HTTP / HTTPS` traffic in the firewall and set a static external IP to my instance, but I can not get my Flask app to listen to any incoming `HTTP requests`.

Running ifconfig does not show the instance's external IP, only the local IP, but I can ping the external IP.

I've already tried using `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)` but it doesn't matter which port I choose to run the server on, the problem persists.

I can access my intance via internet running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`, so I don't really know what is going on here anymore.

I'm clueless as to why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate any help :)

**SOLVED:** Turns out I'm actually dumb. Like I said, my Flask server was running on the 8888 port, so all I had to do was create a firewall rule that used the same port. Now everything's working like it's supposed to! :)